# Cart being dropped when adding multiple packages

Tags: cartthrob

When I try to add multiple packages, any where from about 6-10, the cart will clear itself. I'm wondering if this has to do with the extra processing a package has to go through since the package information is saved as an array and then serialized?
Is it just overloading the server causing it to drop the cart?

Comment: Hi Jake, are you logged in when adding items to the cart? Is there a long pause inbetween each addition? Thanks.

Comment: I happens whether I'm logged in or not. It seems to be directly related to packages. I can add about 5-6 packages to the cart but once I add one more it clears the cart. It doesn't seem to happen when adding single items. There does not appear to be any long pause either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the support engineers has taken a look at this but cannot replicate your issue with our test install.

If you have not already, can you update Cartthrob to the latest version and if you still have the issue, please schedule a support call at http://support.mightybigrobot.com

Thanks!

Comment: I should note that when I mean 5-6 packages, I mean 5-6 "different" packages not just a qty of 5-6. Also, our packages are at least 25 items large, sometimes 50 items.

Comment: Ok, but you'll still need to book a support slot for this Jake. Thanks!